# Linux Debian 11 cinnamon - how to launch a new window on the panel on the right side of the icon instead of in the place of the icon?

Tags: linux, debian, icons, panel

I use Linux Debian 11 with cinnamon desktop and I have some icons on the left side of the panel and when I click on one of them I would like that icon to stay fixed to its place and the new window to be opened next to the right, but instead of this a new window opens in the place of the icon which I clicked and then I can't open a new window of this program by clicking on that icon, because this icon becomes the representation of a new window itself. I can't find any solution in the panel configuration nor in the preferences of that program that is represented by the icon on the left side of the panel (right click on icon -> preferences -> configuration, but I can't find any way to change it). Is there a way to make icons on the panel to launch a new window next to the right instead of the representation of a new window on the panel to be appearing in the place of the primary icon?
[image: This picture quickly illustrates my problem]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the applet. Which one is used there ? 'Grouped window list', 'Window list', 'Windows Quick List'...

Using "System settings"|Applets, you'll find installed applets. Some have a 'configure' button on the right side. You could check there.

If you just want default behaviours, remove and re-add the applet, and voilà

*** edit following your answer ***

You should install both "grouped windows list" and "windows list" together.

for "grouped..." applet, tag "group by application", and untag "show count number", "thumbnails"

To add icons :
From the menu, right clicking on an app's icon give you the option to add a shortcut on the pannel, desktop, or favorites. Choosing pannel add a shortcut in grouped windows list.

Answer (score 0):

@user4089, thank You very much!
Preferences -> applets: and here I searched for "window" and removed "Grouped window list" (not uninstalled, because this is a system applet) and I added "Window list".

But icons appeared on the right side of the panel, and there was no option to add e.g. KolourPaint icon to the panel (like it was in the "Grouped window list" applet), etc., so I added more terminal icons and edited them to executing the command "kolourpaint", etc., and I changed the pictures of icons.

OK, but the icons were still on the right side, and when I moved them to the left (in the panel edit mode), then all new windows were appearing on the left side of the primary launcher icons, causing icons to be moved to the right... :D
When I moved the "show desktop" icon far to the right, I was able to achieve that wonderful icons setting that all new windows appears to the right of the launcher icons. Finally I moved the "show desktop" icon to the left edge of the panel and it didn't spoil that wonderful icons setting :)

I searched for any option like "launch new window next to the right" but I didn't find, and I changed the way the new windows appears by only moving icons along the panel, but such an option would be very helpful.

Thank You for help!

Comment: I edited my answer...